# How do I enable a virtual environment inside an already running python session?

Tags: python, virtualenv

Suppose I have an already open python interpreter running on my system environment and I want to change it to an virtual environment I have to use its packages, is it possible?

Comment: Probably, but why?

Comment: Part of the virtual environment is the interpreter to use. Unless your current session is an instance of that interpreter, you can't switch. It's very unlikely that what you would need to do to alter the Python path is worth it, compared to simply starting a new session.

Comment: My take on this is that, by definition, this is not something you want to do.  Once you have an interpreter running, that interpreter identifies the environment around it, be it a virtual env or a base installation of Python.  The running interpreter should never be forced to utilize some other environment than its own.  If you want to change environments, you want to launch a new interpreter.